# Having trouble calling a member function

Tags: c++, oop

I'm sure my problem is something silly, I don't have much experience with c++ at all.

I'm trying to call a function that will return true if an entered value is already in a set. When I call this function in another function I get an error and i'm not sure why.

Here is where I call the function:

```
Set::Insert(const value_type& entry){
if(!Contains()){...
```

and here is the function I am calling:

```
bool Set::Contains(value_type& entry) const{
int temp = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < used; i++){
    if(data[i] == entry){
        return true;
    }else{
        temp++;
    }
}

if(temp == used) return false;

}
```

There is certainly a better way to do this but for now I am more focused on why it wont work.

The error I am getting is 'no matching function for call to Set::Contains()
but I don't understand why. I have the function prototype.

```
public:
    typedef int value_type;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    static const size_type CAPACITY = 5;
    Set();
    Insert(const value_type& entry);
    Remove();
    bool Contains(value_type& entry) const;
    Print();
    moveForward();
    moveBack();
    ~Set();
```

Comment: `!Contains()` does not pass a parameter to the function. You probably meant `!Contains(entry)`

Comment: I tried that before posting, it also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const value_type&` (which is the type of `entry` in `Set::Insert`) cannot be implicitly cast to a `value_type&` (which is the type of the argument that `Set::Contains` takes). Since `Set::Contains` does not mutate its argument, you should be able to make it take a `const value_type&` also.

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I missed that. Thank you so much.